# What's wrong with sum(65537) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, range

I'm using Python 3.3.2 x64 and I get a wrong result when I apply `sum()` function for a range bigger `65536`:

```
sum(range(65537))
-2147450880
```

This 'scientific' version preload `NumPy` and `SciPy` libraries.

What is the problem?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error, I got `2147516416`. Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: also unable to reproduce. at least CPython internally uses extensible int types, so this wouldn't normally happen, as that prevents integers from overflowing -- the underlying storage just grows

Comment: [repl.it](http://repl.it/) gives the correct answer too

Comment: I strongly recommend against using any environment which does the equivalent of `from numpy import *`.  Not only `sum`, but `any` and `all` are replaced, which can give exactly the opposite answers.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are having problems with `numpy.sum()` instead of Python's built-in `sum()` function. According to [NumPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

> **dtype**: The type of the returned array and of the accumulator in which the elements are summed. By default, the dtype of a is used. An exception is when a has an integer type with less precision than the default platform integer. In that case, the default platform integer is used instead.

Try setting `dtype` manually:

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(range(65537), dtype=np.int64)
```

result:

```
2147516416
```

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk, it worked. I have read about it but I was not very sure how to use it. Thank you.